# How to cross check element is accessible from selected element locator on browser. Without including it into script and running in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

For e.g. I have written a xpath for an element then how to check it is a valid xpath for that element without including it and executing the script in selenium. Same question is with using other element locators like id, css selectors.

Comment: did u tried chrome extensions like chropath or dev inspector tool

Answer (score 1):

Try Chrome Dev tool > Inspector > Console

1. for xpath you can use `$x("valid xpath syntax")`
   [image]
2. for css selector you can use `$$(".cssclass1.cssclass2")`

[image]

Comment: Wow that chrome extension tool is like gem. Thanks for it. And that trick to check element in console is also helpful.